# How to create training operator jobs from kubeflow pipeline?

Tags: kubernetes, kubeflow, kubeflow-pipelines, kfp

How to create training operator jobs from kubeflow pipeline

I want to run the training operators (XGBoostJob specifically) from kubeflow pipeine. Is it possible? Can I get some examples for the same? Most of the examples are not using kubeflow pipelines.